# I have some arrays of questions with each questions contain different types. how to find duplicate values in multidimensional array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, codeigniter-3

Below I have an array list. How to find duplicate values in multidimensional array?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [q_id] => 1
            [pt_type_id] => 1
            [pt_shortcode] => e
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [q_id] => 2
            [pt_type_id] => 2
            [pt_shortcode] => i
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [q_id] => 3
            [pt_type_id] => 2
            [pt_shortcode] => i
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [q_id] => 4
            [pt_type_id] => 1
            [pt_shortcode] => e
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [q_id] => 5
            [pt_type_id] => 3
            [pt_shortcode] => s
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [q_id] => 6
            [pt_type_id] => 4
            [pt_shortcode] => n
        )

)
```

Comment: do you want to find `pt_type_id` duplicates in ? and what to do it after that?

Comment: @AliQorbani  i need to find out  "pt_shortcode" after that calculate  total sum of pt_type_id